# Does it matter if I use water that previously boiled for watering plants?

Tags: watering

A lot of time I have water that was left in the kettle from the previous boiling, and I want to replace them - so a good use would be to water my plants - **does it matter to the plants if the water were pre-boiled?**

What I can think of, is that it can matter since boiled water has [less dissolved oxygen](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/88864/66800) - but I have no idea if for good or bad (or none at all).

Also, if it does matter in someway - is it general for plants, or for specific families?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it does not matter for the plant if the water was previously boiled. Of course let it cool down first. The roots of the plants need indeed oxygen, and therefore you'll need to have holes in the bottom of the pots, because the oxygen is taken up from the air not the water.

So you can use this water for plants, but be careful not to over water any plants (some plants only need water once a week, or every other week).

Comment: Of course as much as they need - I have enough plants to distribute the water  Thanks!